# What exactly is "inputRadius" parameter and how do I choose it?

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use `Cv2.Inpaint` to remove text from images. The current problem I am facing is how to choose input radius. The [documentation for Inpaint](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) describes the parameter like

> **inpaintRadius** – Radius of a circular neighborhood of each point
>   inpainted that is considered by the algorithm.

but this is not very specific (what does "considered by the algorithm" mean, for example). How can I choose a "good" value?

Comment: *"considered by the algorithm"* is referring to a point that the algorithm needs to repaint. It sounds to me like the method is used to fill in areas of an image, and it uses an algorithm that looks at the surrounding image to determine a pattern to use to fill in the area. The `inpaintRadius` would determine the size of area around the pixels being repaintained that will be used for determining a pattern. If you use a small value, only nearby colors and patterns will be used to fill in the area, and vice-versa.

Comment: @RufusL That makes sense. Thanks.